# USB device is not recognized on HP laptop with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, hp

I am trying to connect a USB braille cell device to my HP Folio 9470m laptop running Ubuntu 14.04.2 (amd64), but it fails with the following errors (from `dmesg`):

```
[ 1689.038374] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 1694.057635] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[ 1694.169706] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 1699.189291] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/all, error -110
```

...and so on

The same device works fine on the same laptop under Windows 7 and under Fedora 21. It also works fine on a Dell laptop running Ubuntu 14.04.2 (amd64).

All other devices I tried (usb stick, hard drive, keyboard, mouse) work perfectly fine. The device also fails on the same computer with the same `dmesg` when running ubuntu-live.

Since it works on other computers and other Linux distributions I wonder if it is some Ubuntu-HP pairing problem.

**Update:**

Here is the info from `lsusb` (obtained from Dell laptop on which the device works):

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0452:0100 Mitsubishi Electronics America, Inc.
```

and from `dmesg`:

```
[51914.942425] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[51915.038927] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0452, idProduct=0100
[51915.038940] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=7
[51915.038949] usb 2-1.1: Product: M30245 Starter Kit
[51915.038957] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Mitsubishi Electronics America Inc.
[51915.038965] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: Ver. 0.9
```

When I successfully connect the device to my HP laptop running Fedora, `dmesg` shows the following:

```
[  303.569148] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  303.737434] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0452, idProduct=0100
[  303.737444] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=7
[  303.737449] usb 1-4: Product: M30245 Starter Kit
[  303.737453] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Mitsubishi Electronics America Inc.
[  303.737457] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: Ver. 0.9
[  303.738015] usb 1-4: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
```

I have also tried this device on another HP laptop (Ultrabook) with Ubuntu and it does not work either.

Comment: Can you provide the USB brand/model ID for this device. eg. output from **`lsusb`** that changes with device attached.

Comment: Just included the lsusb from the working computer (Dell with Ububtu). Nothing changes in `lsusb` outputs when I connect the device to HP laptop (when running Ubuntu).